# Point of no return

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Now that we are here,
>   there's no going back,
>   just get another,
>   there's more in a pack,
>
> Link me together,
>   to make me longer,
>   or double me up,
>   to make me stronger,
>
> I wonder how many
>   there are of me,
>   I'll probably end up
>   in the sea,
>
> Can you name me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing

> Ziptie

Now that we are here,
there's no going back,

> if a ziptie is closed it cant be opened without cutting it

---

> This is not completely correct, because a ziptie can be opened, but most of the time they are cutted

just get another,
there's more in a pack,

> self-explanatory

Link me together,
to make me longer,

> you can link one end of a ziptie with the end of an other ziptie, constructing a chain of zipties

or double me up,
to make me stronger,

> two zipties at the same spot are stronger than on

I wonder how many
there are of me,

> zipties are commonly used, there should be a great amount of them in the world

I'll probably end up
in the sea,

> zipties are made of plastic, and most of our plastic ends up in the sea

Answer (score 10):

This sounds a bit like

> a polymer

Now that we are here,
there's no going back,

> Once a monomer is attached to the polymer, it's usually very difficult to remove again

just get another,
there's more in a pack,

> This is how polymers are made - by continually adding monomers

Link me together,
to make me longer,

> You can join two polymer strands end-to-end

or double me up,
to make me stronger,

> You can intertwine or bond multiple polymer strands to make them stronger

I wonder how many
there are of me,

> Plastic is one of the most widely used materials

I'll probably end up
in the sea,

> A *lot* of plastic ends up in the sea

Can you name me?

Comment: Very good answer, I was thinking of something usually made from a polymer though (Nylon is this case). I actually researched polymers when coming up with this riddle.

Answer (score 6):

Could it be a

> plastic bag

Now that we are here, there’s no going back

> once you put all your stuff in you won’t want to switch bags

just get another, there’s more in a pack

> if one breaks, they can be bought in packs so just get another one

link me together, to make me longer

> some kinds of bags (like trash bags) can be opened on both ends to link several together

or double me up, to make me stronger

> this is often done with heavy items, specifically when grocery shopping (e.g. milk)

I wonder how many there are of me

> plastic bags are mass produced

I’ll probably end up in the sea

> Litter can be blown by the wind, or other factors can make it go to the sea

Kind of stretching it but it fits.

TrojanByAccident thanks for idea

Answer (score 5):

You might be

> a cigarette?

Now that we are here,
there's no going back,

> This - along with the title - could refer to cigarette addiction (which it's very hard to turn back from)

just get another,
there's more in a pack,

> Cigarettes come in packs of 20+

Link me together,
to make me longer,

> Smoking multiple cigarettes back-to-back (when done routinely) is known as "chain smoking;" each cigarette, then, could be thought of as a link in a chain, and each one would make the chain longer

or double me up,
to make me stronger,

> If you hold two side by side, they'd be harder to break?  (There's also the fact that a "fag" is a word for a cigarette, and a "faggot" is a bundle of sticks, and a bundle of sticks is much harder to break than a single stick - but I'm not sure if that's too much of a stretch.)

I wonder how many
there are of me,

> It's near impossible to count the number of cigarettes in the world

I'll probably end up
in the sea,

> People often litter their cigarette butts on the ground; litter like this often ends up in waterways, which eventually drain to the oceans

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> Gum

Now that we are here,
there's no going back,

> You can't put gum back in the box (without ruining the rest

just get another,
there's more in a pack,

> There are (most of the time) multiple pieces of gum in one pack

Link me together,
to make me longer,

> The soft gums (without a hard shell) can be pressed together, which you can use to make it longer

or double me up,
to make me stronger,

> If you take two, you have more to chew one, hence you have to be stronger to be able to chew

I wonder how many
there are of me,

> There are a load of pieces of gum

I'll probably end up
in the sea,

> Gum doesn't just "fade" like a banana peel, some people do weird stuff? i don't really know, but it could still fit

Answer (score 0):

You could be a (cheesy warning)

> Condom

Now that we are here,
there's no going back,

> When you end up in the process of using it, you all know there is no turning back

just get another,
there's more in a pack,

> They come in packets of at least 3, to keep you going

Link me together,
to make me longer,

> You can use another after another, to elongate the mating process

or double me up,
to make me stronger,

> You could use one on top of another, to strengthen the durability

I wonder how many
there are of me,

> Really, nobody knows how many there are

I'll probably end up
in the sea

> A lot of people end up throwing them in the toilet instead of the garbage bin (which is wrong on so many levels), thus making them end up in the sea

Comment: Though technically I think doubling them up makes them weaker...